# How do extract a sub string from a string after a certain character?

Tags: c, substring

I am trying to implement redirection. I have an input from the user and I am trying to extract the output file from it. I am using strstr() to find the first occurrence of '>'. From there I can extract the rest of the string but I am unsure how to accomplish this.

I have tried using strstr() along with strcpy() but with no luck.

```
// char_position is the pointer to the character '>'
// output_file is the file that I need to extract
// line is the original string

// example of input: ls -l > test.txt

char *chr_position = strstr(line, ">");
char *output_file = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(line) + 1));
strcpy(output_file + (chr_position - line), chr_position // something here?);
printf("The file is %s\n", output_file);
```

Expected results is build a string from the > until the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
strcpy(output_file + (chr_position - line), chr_position);
```

You start copying into `output_file` not at the start but `chr_position - line` bytes **after** that.  Just start at the beginning:

```
strcpy(output_file, chr_position + 1);
```

Note also that that since `chr_position` points to the `>` character you want to start copying at least 1 byte after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strstr quite easily to accomplish this:

```
char inarg[] = "ls -l > test.txt";

char  *pos;
pos = strstr(inarg, "> ") + 2;
printf("%s\n", pos);   // Will print out 'test.txt'
```

This works by looking for the "> " combination in the string. The +2 after the strstr call is to allow for the fact that strstr will return a pointer to the string '> test.txt' and we want to skip the '> ' (2 bytes with the trailing space) so we add 2 to the pointer so that it ends up pointing to text that we wish to extract.